# for while loop error once I add more than 1 remove() function

Tags: python

When I run the following code it runs smoothly.

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

sections = 3

for i in range(sections):
        dellist1 = random.choice(list1)
        print(dellist1)
        list1.remove(dellist1)
```

The idea is for it to randomly choose a strong from the list and then remove that strong from the list so that once it's run again there's no chance of repeats.

However, once I start adding additional lists to the loop like this:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list2 = ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

sections = 3

for i in range(sections):
        dellist1 = random.choice(list1)
        print(dellist1)
        list1.remove(dellist1)

        dellist2 = random.choice(list2)
        print(dellist2)
        list2.remove(dellist2)
```

I get the following error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list.

Comment: what is `core`?

Comment: Apologies, I copy and pasted original program without thoroughly adjusting it for the example.

Comment: your code should now work. it doesn't produce an error on my side.

Comment: What is the output from the print statements when you get the error?

Comment: It does indeed. I really appreciate your time.